# Why does the class in Intent have the "::class.java" suffix?

Tags: android, kotlin

An intent in Kotlin:

```
val intent = Intent(this, OtherActivity::class.java)
```

why can't it just be:

```
val intent = Intent(this, OtherActivity)
```

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second argument of that Intent constructor requires the *class* of the Activity you want to create. While it would be convenient to get the class just by using the class name `OtherActivity`, Java (and Kotlin) syntax does not support this.

Instead, Java provides the `.class` syntax  (`OtherActivity.class`) and Kotlin provides`::class` for the Kotlin class, and `::class.java` (`OtherActivity::class.java`) for the Java class, which is what the Intent constructor needs.

Comment: Is there any reason not to use the Kotlin class if you're writing your android app in Kotlin? (`OtherActivity:class`)

Comment: There is no reason you can't use the Kotlin class for your own code, but the Android platform classes like Intent are written in Java, not Kotlin, so they use `java.lang.Class`. They can't use the Kotlin class because it doesn't exist to them.

Comment: `::class.java` isn't really special syntax. `.java` is just a property on `KClass`, just like there is an extension `.kotlin` property on `Class`.

Comment: Is `OtherActivity::class.java` what the `Intent` constructor needs because `Intent` is a Java class? @LeoAso

Answer (score 2):

Using `::class`, Kotlin supplies a `KClass`, which can be used for various things. However, there are still Java packages which use `Class` instead, and among those is Intent. A KClass is not a Class, which means Kotlin needs to have a way to access the regular Java Class.

The `Intent` class is originally written in Java, which means it uses a `Class`. `OtherActivity::class` returns a KClass, and a KClass can't be passed as a `Class`.

`SomeClass::class.java` exists for interop purposes. You can also use a `Class` instead of `KClass` in your Kotlin code; you won't get warnings about that like you'd get about for an instance `Object` over `Any`. But you still periodically need a `Class` with Java interop.

---

Why specifically they went with `::class.java` is not something anyone can answer, aside the developers of the language itself.

Comment: `.javaClass` still exists, but it is not the same as `::class.java`. `.javaClass` is meant to be used on instances, not the class itself. Using it on a class name references the class's _companion object_, not the class itself. That's why Android Studio warns when you use it on a class.

Comment: I never said it didn't exist, but I assumed it was a deprecated feature given the warning.

Answer (score 1):

Because Intent is a java class and expects an Android Context and a Java Class (The activity) as the arguments.

Comment: But doesn't it already know `OtherActivity` is a java class? why does it have to say `::class.java`

Comment: I can only assume when you instantiate the Intent class in Kotlin, the single word syntax would reference a Kotlin class..which is not a java class. My guess so I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

if you are okay with a little bit of namespace polution and this is a real concern in your team you can allways declare the following top level function:

```
inline fun <reified T> Intent(context: Context){
    return Intent(context, T::class.java)
}
```

Which you would call doing the following:

```
val intent = Intent<MyActivity>(this)
```

Or if you want you can declare it as an extension function on Context:

```
inline fun <reified T> Context.Intent(){
    return Intent(this, T::class.java)
}
```

An use it directly like this:

```
val intent = Intent<MyActivity>()
```